# HT7333-A LDO quiescent current

Tags: power, integrated-circuit, ldo

I've sourced some HT7333-A LDOs in SOT-89 package from random AliExpress seller for my battery-powered project. They were quite affordable and I saw some posts from people using these in batter-powered apps.
[Datasheet](http://www.angeladvance.com/HT73xx.pdf) on that IC states it has about 4 uA quiescent current and requires only 2 x 10 uF capacitors. I've soldered 2 (input and output) SMD ceramic caps in 0603 rated and 10 uF and measured to be around 9.3 uF in fact.
Casual Li-Ion battery are used as input, at 4.083 V, the output from LDO are at 3.263 V (ok for me, within datasheet specified range). But when I measure current flow while output are left "floated" it reads at around 1.2 mA, which is definitely not good for battery app. 
I haven't connected real load yet. But why is it sinking 1.2 mA while no load are connected? Am I "happen" to get some sort if fake ICs or flawed component (I've checked only 1 IC from the strip so far)?

PS: Asking more out of curiosity, I've already ordered other low quiescent current LDOs from reliable supplier.

Comment: "sourced from random seller on aliexpress" means "might or might not be related to what is in the datasheet". So, really, don't do that. Where do you think do people get counterfeit components from? Obviously, you'll get inferior quality for something that is already cheap when bought from common, reputable distributors like digikey.com, mouser.com, farnell.com, …

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP bought something of untrackable quality and now wonders why it doesn't follow specification.

Comment: So, now you're in the process of learning a valuable lesson. Hmm I wonder what that could be? Oh yeah.... Reputable manufacturers and reputable suppliers.

Comment: @Andyaka it's not even about "reputable" and "not so reputable"; OP *deliberately* bought something from a random seller. I always wonder whether people would do the same e.g. with hardware they buy to build a garden table. "hey, this guy has screws half the price of the cheapest screws from the hardware store, and I only had to travel out to this dark backroad, promise to come alone, and buy screw packages out of a van without a license plate. So looking forward to build that bench on which I'll sit my beloved wife!"

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback. I wish it were only a bit less sarcastic :) Unfortunately it's not easy to order parts from such reliable suppliers like @MarcusMüller mentioned in my country. They don't ship here or it ends up too much on shipping costs. I really wasn't aware that such cheap ICs, like LDOs could end behaving like this. Never encountered something like that from other ICs I bought from China. But the answer below by Olin Lathrop explained why that could happen pretty well.

Comment: The response are sarcastic because those answering feel you really should know better.  This isn't about electronics knowledge, but basic life knowledge.

Comment: @NStorm Mouser literally ships everywhere in the world as long as there's no UN embargo against your country.

Comment: @MarcusMüller their prices are already higher than any other supplier. Yet their website claims all prices includes shipping and all shipping are free in fact it's not. After I've placed an order with them, they transferred it to some local component re-seller who invoiced me for the shipping. I've contacted Mouser about that and they told me that is ok. Wouldn't not deal with them again. Time lost and false promises.  Did I mentioned 8+ weeks of wait time? :( I found a way to order from DigiKey via mail forwarding company already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> random AliExpress seller ... why is it sinking 1.2 mA while no load

The first statement seems to answer the second.

You buy parts from a questionable seller in some dark corner of the internet, and you're actually wondering why they don't meet spec?  Seriously!?

If you can observe this symptom on real parts you know are full production from the same manufacturer the datasheet is from, we can delve into this more.  Otherwise this is a waste of time.

*Think* about it.  Your a manufacturer of knockoff parts in east Asia someplace.  70% of parts meet full specs, so you sell those as second source parts like the real thing.  20% are close enough, so you sell them to hobby places where the customers buy on price only and generally aren't sophisticated enough to notice the difference.  The remaining 10% are pretty bad, so you sell them to your second cousin's wife's brother in law who has about ten different "company" names thru which he sells stuff on Alibaba and the like.  These go to people that don't look past the low price and think they're getting a "deal".  Hey, these marks will never find you, and it's better than tossing the lot in the ditch behind the factory.  That's full of leaking drums of used paint thinner already anyway.